# custom content type

Tags: entities

I have created a custom content type (Testimonial), with the following fields: customer name, testimonial, company name. Each of them is stored in a different table.

How can I use the records to display in the front end? Is it advisable to use custom content type for this purpose?

Comment: Look into the Views module ( http://drupal.org/project/views ) as it will allow you to show your (and all other) content types in all kinds of ways on your site.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal has is own storage system in database. Your don't really need to know how datas are stored and even if datas are in severals tables, you can use functions like [node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7) or [node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7), which are awesome because you do not write any joined sql queries and fields datas are automaticly returned in a node object

Use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module to display a list of nodes of a certain type.